# Google MLKIT mobile base model Label List?

Tags: firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am desperately looking for a complete List of Labels for the Image Labeling base model with 400 labels as described here https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling
The page only gives a few examples but I need a complete List to map indexes String resources in different languages. Anyone found documentation for the model?

Answer (score 2):

We just published the [label list](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling/label-map) on the ML Kit website, hope this helps!